# Role tags ignored when applied on include directive alongside with_items

Tags: ansible, provisioning

So I am experiencing a strange issue with ansible not being able to execute some tagged `include` tasks in roles.

After some digging, it appears that the ability to run the specified task broke as soon as `include` is associated with `with_items`.

For example, my simple role contains:

```
role/tasks/main.yml
---
- include: test.yml
  tags:
    - my_role_test


role/tasks/test.yml
---
- debug:
    msg: "It works"
```

When I run my playbook with `--tags=my_role_test`, I can see the expected output:

```
[20:18:52] test : debug | server | SUCCESS | 593ms
{
  - msg: It works
}
```

However, if I change my `main.yml` file and add `with_items`to the include task:

```
role/tasks/main.yml
---
- include: test.yml
  with_items:
    - A
    - B
  tags:
    - my_role_test
```

I got this output:

```
[20:15:41] test : include
[20:15:41]  ➥ system | included: /test/tasks/test.yml for server
[20:15:41]  ➥ system | included: /test/tasks/test.yml for server
[20:15:41]  ➥ system | -- Play recap --
```

and the tasks are not being executed.

Am I doing something wrong ? Is this an ansible issue ? Do you know a workaround ?

My ansible version is 2.5.2.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically, [ansible changed the way to manage tags inheritance since Ansible 2.5](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/porting_guides/porting_guide_2.5.html#dynamic-includes-and-attribute-inheritance). The only solution is to put the tags directly on each task of the included task file or use static import_*. Note, that for dynamic include, the use of a block section may help:

```
role/tasks/main.yml
---
- include: test.yml
  with_items:
    - A
    - B


role/tasks/test.yml
---
block:
  - debug:
      msg: "It works"
  - debug:
      msg: "It works again"
tags:
  - my_role_test
```

Answer (score 2):

The main question to ask is your case is:

**Set Tags per Item in a Loop with Ansible.**

It looks like an unresolved problem. https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/19115

Please check this: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/864638/ansible-set-tags-per-item-in-with-items-loop

Comment: Nice catch for the GitHub issue. I found another which was very similar but not this one. So sadly, there is nothing I can do at the moment to bypass that. I din't get the point about your server fault link. Am I missing something ?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/864638/ansible-set-tags-per-item-in-with-items-loop

Answer (score 1):

Try "include_tasks" instead of "include" as suggested in https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/19115
"... this issue is resolved in recent ansible versions, but will require a change from include to utilize include_tasks instead."
Details are available
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/porting_guides/porting_guide_2.5.html#dynamic-includes-and-attribute-inheritance

Comment: The issue has been marked as solved, but sadly my problem remains currently.